# how to clear tracking when using SignInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync in EF Core 5

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I try to implement login using Identity in blazor server, I want user to login inside blazor component rather than razor page ,I am not be able to using "PasswordSignInAsync" in razor component It will throw an exception, So I using "CheckPasswordSignInAsync" instead after success and I pass along to PasswordSignInAsync in middleware,but I have facing issue now when user try login with wrong password and try login again with the same user "signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync" throw exception about entity being track, How can I resolve that ?

I really Appricate for you help :)

Comment: I found the issue, Because of Startup.cs in ConfigureService I have this 
 "option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
                  .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)); " So I remove " .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)" Now It's work like expected

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.